# Best and easiest way to delete a layer by a specific time in the After Effects timeline

Tags: after-effects, compositing, video-player

I use Adobe After Effects (Last version) for video editing

I created a composition with a video, shape and null Object. So far everything work well.
Now I want to hide the layer from a certain point in my timeline.

Let say my timeline is 10s, I want my layer to be visible at the first 3s and then to be invisible the remaining seconds

[image]

What is the best and easiest way to perform that?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a key frame (or more than one at different points) on the Opacity control. You can get to it by selecting the layer and pressing <kbd>T</kbd>. Or open up all the triangles to find it. Set the opacity to zero to make the layer invisible.
[image]

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood - I'm not sure how well you know after effects. Maybe you mean you just want to trim the end of a layer? You can do this by selecting the layer at a certain time, and pressing the ] key.

Comment: By the way, this is an old but very good beginner's guide to After Effects. You might find it useful: http://www.videocopilot.net/basic/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an expression that sets the opacity of your layer to 0 once you've hit a certain time in your timeline. You should be able to code this properly in Java or the basic expression-language. A syntax should look somewhat like this:

> if (comptime)>"yourtime"
>
> opacity.yourlayer=0

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I know Java, and please, how to create that expression in AE? I very newbie with AE